# Register RxApprenticeServer dll Inventor api

Tags: autodesk-inventor

I created and standalone application that reads and writes Inventor files by using the apprentice server.
How can I register only the RxApprentice dll without installing the Autodesk inventor view.

I've tried with regsv32 but I'm getting the following
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kq7U.png)

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Comment: There's not code in the screenshot but only the error message: "the dll was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found" that i'm getting when trying to register the dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working under <150mb, and skipping the need for Autodesk Single Sign-On, Autodesk Desktop App and Autodesk Genuine Service.

I used [github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://%20github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) CLI with a depth of 100, extracted all the .dll files that were in the same folder as RxApprenticeServer, and added it to a new folder.

Then I found the CSLID of RxApprenticeServer and manually registered the .dll to this new location. And tadaa, it works.

I made an installer, use at your own risk. This is for Inventor 2022 https://github.com/sbrandsen/LightApprenticeServer

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is NOT possible.

First, you do not know which libraries (DLLs) the apprentice is using.

Second, it is a free but licensed program by Autodesk

Comment: I used this tool to know which libraries is apprentice using 
https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies
I don't think this library is licensed by autodesk. I think it is possible to register it but I don't know if regsvr32 is the correct way to do it.